# How can I import something as both a type and a value in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have some TypeScript code that has values as the `PublicKey` type, that also uses the `PublicKey` constructor to turns strings into `PublicKey`s.

```
import type { Connection, Keypair, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";
```

This fails with the error:

```
Duplicate identifier 'PublicKey'
```

How can I use `Keypair` both as a type and a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use an [`as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-a-single-export-from-a-module) to rename the import:

```js
import type { Connection, Keypair, PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js";
import { PublicKey as PublicKeyConstructor } from "@solana/web3.js";
```